# Android/LibGDX - Integer cannot be casted to float (but it works fine for desktop)

Tags: java, android, casting, libgdx

I create a 2D game using the game library LibGDX. When the game starts, some variables shoud be filled with the values of a `Preferences` file (see: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences).

In my`GamePreferences` class, I have an Array(Vector3) called `helpingRects`. In a for-loop, the array should be filled with the values of the prefs file:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numOfHelpingRects; i++)
    {
        helpingRects.add(new Vector3(prefs.getFloat("helpingrect" + String.valueOf(i) + "x"), prefs.getFloat("helpingrect" + String.valueOf(i) + "y"), prefs.getFloat("helpingrect" + String.valueOf(i) + "l")));
    }
```

So, for example, for `i = 0`, a new `helpingRects` vector will be added where the x-value can be found in the preferences file at the entry "helpingrect0x" etc.

Since I use LibGDX, I can run the game on multiple platforms. On dekstop, the code works fine but on Android, I get an error message:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 23941
Process: de.ej.facharbeitsspiel, PID: 13218
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Float
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getFloat(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:256)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidPreferences.getFloat(AndroidPreferences.java:101)
at de.ej.facharbeitsspiel.Tools.GamePreferences.load(GamePreferences.java:65)
at de.ej.facharbeitsspiel.MainClass.create(MainClass.java:26)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:275)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1633)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1354)
```

So basically, the variable `i`, which is an `int` obviously, can't be cast to a float value. Changing the `i` from `int` to `float` doesn't help because in this case, `i` equals `0.0/1.0` etc. but this bad since my entries in the .prefs are not called "helpingrect0.0x" etc.

Does somebody know a solution for this problem? Thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you want to get them as `Integer`? Your stacktrace suggest that the values are type of `Integer` why would you use `getFloat`? Anyways you can cast it with `(float) Integernumber`

Comment: Vector3 is a class that requires `float` values. And I can't cast the `i` to a `float` because of the reason I mentioned above.

Comment: @erik4thewinners  how you put value in preference, show me that code ?

Comment: Okay, I "solved" it, I just had to reinstall the app on Android. Now the code works fine. Anyway, thank you

Comment: I think what's happening here is that Android's SharedPreferences is used the boxed versions of primitives. It already saved an Integer, and when you call `getFloat()` it's trying to cast to Float internally, resulting in the CCE. You could have alternatively fixed this by writing a float to the same preference, or clearing app data for the installed app.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You could use `float i = 0` if you then use `String.format("%.0f", i)`

Second, looking at your code I find it hard to believe the error is because `i` is an `int`.

Just for testing, try hard-coding one line to see if that works:

```
helpingRects.add(
    new Vector3(prefs.getFloat("helpingrect0x"), 
    prefs.getFloat("helpingrect0y"), 
    prefs.getFloat("helpingrect0l")));
```

My guess is that the above will not work, which would then show that the issue is not with `i` being an `int`.

EDIT:
The above could be extended, as follows:

```
float x = prefs.getFloat("helpingrect0x");
float y = prefs.getFloat("helpingrect0y");
float l = prefs.getFloat("helpingrect0l");
helpingRects.add(new Vector3(x, y, l));
```

This would further help to norrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

User Tenfour04 has the right idea here. Android's preference documentation shows that if your value doesn't exist it will use the default value you supply it, but if it does already exist, it will return that value. This happened to me recently when I updated one of my preference values from an integer to a float, as the value already existed in the preferences in the integer format. Usually, all you have to do is clear your app data (or uninstall your app) to get these preferences cleared and then it wont retrieve this old value. Sometimes on newer Android devices this is not the case. If an Android device is running Marshmallow or higher, you might have to change `allowBackup="false"` in the manifest. If it is set to true, uninstalling the app or clearing the data will not clear the preferences.